# Extjs 4 gridpanel dynamic color coding Row/Cell

Tags: dynamic, extjs4, color-coding

I would like to dynamically change the background color of the row or sometimes a cell of the grid panel of EXTJS4. Is there a way to this?

I have to query to my php and retrieve data set that I will then determine what color will each data set be. Is this possible? like I said I was hoping it would be dynamic.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code(your try)... so that we can able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What dynamic states here ?

1. If you like to change the color on loadin time, use `renderer` on the column mapping.

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
    .red{background-color: red;}
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.onReady(function(){
   Ext.QuickTips.init();

   var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
       fields: ['name', 'value'],
       data: [['A', 1], ['B', 2]]
   });
   var renderer = function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
       if (value == colIndex) {
           metadata.css = 'red';
       }
       return colIndex;
   }
   var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
       {header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
       {header: '1', dataIndex: 'value', renderer: renderer},
       {header: '2', dataIndex: 'value', renderer: renderer},
       {header: '3', dataIndex: 'value', renderer: renderer},
       {header: '4', dataIndex: 'value', renderer: renderer},
       {header: '5', dataIndex: 'value', renderer: renderer}
   ]);
   var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
       store: store,
       cm: cm,
       listeners: {
           cellclick: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
               if (colIndex > 0) {
                   var rec = grid.store.getAt(rowIndex);
                   rec.set('value', colIndex);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   grid.render(document.body);
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. If you like to change the color on latet point based on any condition use `addRowCls` of table view class.

   ```
   listeners : {
   select : function(cellModel, record, rowIndex) {
        var myGrid = this.items.get('gridItemId');                          
        myGrid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'row-style');
   },
   ```
3. apply in `root config` itself, refer below link for example.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?120001-Help-with-dynamic-row-color-in-grid

Thanks